# Dockerized Keycloak gives CORS errors

Tags: docker, keycloak, swagger-ui, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway application running on port 8080. I have a dockerized Keycloak instance on port 8888. I am in development environment on my own computer. I cannot get documentation hosted by swagger on http://localhost:8080/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html. The error is:
[image: Swagger CORS error]

Here are the client properties of my realm:
[image: Keycloak realm client properties]

Here is my gateway configuration:

```
server:
  port: '8080'
  forward-headers-strategy: framework
spring:
  application:
    name: gatewayservice
  codec:
    log-request-details: true
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: 'http://localhost:${server.port}'
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - DELETE
            allowedHeaders: '*'
            maxAge: 30
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
      routes:
        - id: userOperations
          uri: http://localhost:9010
          predicates:
            - Path=/usermanagement/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/usermanagement/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
        - id: fileOperations
          uri: lb://blogapp-webflux
          predicates:
            - Path=/file/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/file/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 500
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1000
                redis-rate-limiter.requestedTokens: 1
            #- RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie

        - id: blogOperations
          uri: http://localhost:9009
          predicates:
            - Path=/blogapp/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/blogapp/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
        - id: openapi
          uri: http://localhost:${server.port}
          predicates:
            - Path=/v3/api-docs/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/v3/api-docs/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}/v3/api-docs

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            token-uri: http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/blogapp/protocol/openid-connect/token
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/blogapp/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            userinfo-uri: http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/blogapp/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
            cors: true
        registration:
          blogapp:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: blogapp
            client-secret: FsZL17sZd2cSp7bSnCrDdIcS6yuqefC6
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/blogapp"

#Publish Application(Register with Eureka)
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    urls:
      - name: blogapp
        url: /v3/api-docs/blogapp
      - name: blogapp-webflux
        url: /v3/api-docs/file
      - name: blogapp-usermanagement
        url: /v3/api-docs/usermanagement

logging.level:
  org.springframework.cloud.gateway: TRACE
  org.springframework.security: DEBUG
  org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client: TRACE
  org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping: TRACE
  org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter: TRACE
  org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor: TRACE
```

Here is my confiuration bean for gateway:

```
package scalefocus.blogapp.config;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
  private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
    // -- Swagger UI v2
    "/v2/api-docs",
    "/swagger-resources",
    "/swagger-resources/**",
    "/configuration/ui",
    "/configuration/security",
    "/swagger-ui.html",
    "/webjars/**",
    "/configuration/**",
    // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI)
    "/v3/api-docs/**",
    "/v3/api-docs.yaml",
    "/swagger-ui/**",
    "/register"
    // other public endpoints of your API may be appended to this array

  };

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange(
            exchanges ->
                exchanges.pathMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated())
        .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
    return http.build();
  }


}
```

I tried commenting out the globalCors configuration nevertheless took the same error.  [Full code](https://github.com/cokutan/blogapplication/tree/develop)

I have search for CORS errors related to Keycloak. Most of the issues stated that web-origins field of keycloak server must contain the URL of application so I have tried the following values for web-origins:

```
http://localhost:8080
http://127.0.0.1:8080
http://*PUBLIC_IP*:8080
http://*Keycloak docker engine internal IP*:8080
```

with no luck.

I realized that when web-origins is entered like `http://locahost:8080`and I access my Swagger trough localhost I get a response 200 with cors failure, but when I access through  `http://127.0.0.1:8080` then I get 400 with cors failure. So I think I have no problem with web-origins if I use `http://locahost:8080`. But nevertheless the headers are not appended.